# I am having difficulties in understanding the sentence, (Parse this sentence please.)

Tags: grammar, syntax, parsing

Nothing worth having comes easy...

Comment: Is it easier to understand if you think of it as "Nothing *which is* worth having comes easy"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[come easy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20easy)" means "*to be easy to achieve or accomplish*".

The sentence is saying that none of the things which are worth having are easy to achieve.

It takes effort to get things worth having or it's difficult to get things that are worth having. Here "*things*" does not only mean objects but also other concepts like a good education, happiness, nice home etc.